# WCF failing is NOD32 is installed

Tags: wcf, nod32

I've an app using WCF (with WSHttpBinding), which is failing in computers where ESET NOD32 is installed.... There's a windows kernel service called ekrn.exe that starts using lots of CPU (near 100%) and makes the app fail after 1 minute. The error thrown by the application is:

"Client is unable to finish the security negotiation within the configured timeout. The current negotiation leg is 1."

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply consult NOD32 if they have a newer version for you. As far as I know, some versions of NOD32 is interrupting socket related applications on Windows.